# Build Docker image in Jenkins (in Docker image) - Cloud docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I try to learn how to configure Jenkins (in the Docker container) to build Docker Images based on a Dockerfile.

At first I installed DockerToolbox. (OS  Windows 7 Home)

Then I pulled latest Jenkins image from Dockerhub, ran container and logged in as admin.

Based on this tutorial: https://www.katacoda.com/courses/jenkins/build-docker-images I try to  configure the plugin to communicate with a Docker host/daemon. (step 3)

In (Jenkins/configure/Cloud section) I have to fill the Name and Docker-Url then Test Connection.

In the Docker terminal I typed `docker-machine config` to get Url.

Unfortunately after Testing connection I get exception below:

```
shaded.org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: shaded.org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:481)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.VersionCmdExec.execute(VersionCmdExec.java:26)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.VersionCmdExec.execute(VersionCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:23)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(DockerCloud.java:698)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:335)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:175)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:108)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:236)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: shaded.org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: shaded.org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:151)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
```

I'm not sure whether I'm missing something or perhaps there is more efficient approach.

Thank you in advance for a hint.

Cloud settings:

[cloud settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VarmP.jpg)

Comment: Could you please post your configs for Docker Cloud section?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for following the Katacoda scenario. It sounds like the Docker Daemon is not listening on a HTTPS port. The `docker-machine` command will return the IP address of the Docker VM, but by default, the daemon does not listen on a HTTPS port and only via Unix Sockets.

As you're on the same machine, you could try using something like `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` or `/var/run/docker.sock` instead of a IP/Port.

If you want to use IP/Port, you need to modify the Docker Daemon settings, with boot2docker this is done via https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3859

Comment: When put  unix:///var/run/docker.sock in Docker URL I got this exception:
 `org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketException: Permission denied (socket: /run/docker.sock) `
Using ssh I found config file with docker settings in /var/lib/boot2docker/profile:
[boot2docker config]( http://imgur.com/a/SIO9L)
I tried to follow some tips including  DOCKER_OPTS, but didn’t work for me. I’m a newbie in this matter so perhaps it’s a good direction but I don’t pay attention to some details. Could you please point out more precisely what needs to be done to grant permission?